# error on mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

my code is following iam getting a error on "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource..." help me to solve this

```
<?php
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];

#defauts
$maxRows_p = 10;
$pageNum_p = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_p'])) {
  $pageNum_p = $_GET['pageNum_p'];
}
$startRow_p = $pageNum_p * $maxRows_p;
$limit = ' LIMIT '.$startRow_p.', '.$maxRows_p;



//BUILD Addition Search Conditions
if(isset($_REQUEST['district']) && ($_REQUEST['district'] != 'All'))
    $search = ' district = '.$_REQUEST['district'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['city']) && ($_REQUEST['city'] != 'All'))
    $search = ' city = '.$_REQUEST['city'];


$search= ' availibility = "0" ';

$searchStr = @implode(' and ',$search);     

$sql = 'select * FROM properties WHERE type= "'.$type.'" and ';
$sql .= $searchStr;

## DEBUGi
//if($debugP) echo 'Zip Code Radius SQL<hr>'.$sql;

//Add column sorting

if($_REQUEST['sort'] != '')
    $sort = ' order by added asc ';
else
    $sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];

### DEBUG
if($debugP) echo 'Advanced Search Sql<hr>'.$sql;

$error['Results'] = 'Sorry no properties found.';



### Finished Building search sql and execting #####
$sql_with_limit = $sql . $sort . $limit;


if($debugP)
    echo "<hr>Property Search with Limit SQL: $sql_with_limit";     

//Perform search
$searchResults = mysql_query($sql.$sql_with_limit); 

### BUILD OUTPUT ####

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_p'])) {
  $totalRows_p = $_GET['totalRows_p'];
} else {
  if($debugP)
      echo "<hr>Property with out limit SQL: $sql $sort";
  $all_p = mysql_query($sql.$sort);
  $totalRows_p = mysql_num_rows($all_p); //$totalRows_p = mysql_num_rows($all_p);
  if($debugP)
      echo "<br>Result Rows $totalRows_p";
}
$totalPages_p = ceil($totalRows_p/$maxRows_p)-1;


if($debugP)
    echo "<hr>Builting Query String for Limit: ";

//Build query string
foreach($_GET as $name => $value){
    if($name != "pageNum_p")
        $queryString_p .= "&$name=$value";
}

if($debugP)
    echo $queryString_p;                    
?>
```

Comment: Pray, you don't get a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). This code screams SQL injection. Also, consult [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after `mysql_query()`.

Comment: It seems like your trying to use the "$search" variable as an array... but it's actually a variable.... so the implode shouldn't work and that might be causing the problem. replace $search with $search[]

Answer (score 0):

It probably because that MySQL was unable to process your SQL statement as supplied. 
Try changing your mysql_query line to the following so that you get some debug information,
just try below code for your query

```
 $all_p = mysql_query($sql.$sort) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
```

Thanx.

Comment: iam getting the following error 
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
select * FROM properties WHERE type= "0" and

Comment: ok..i think i got it, your query is **select * FROM properties WHERE type= "0" and** but after 'and' you have put $sort variable for **ORDER BY** statement..so for ORDER BY statement you no need to put AND after type="0"..just remove **'and'** then try it again..

Comment: if you want to put search variable after you **where** condition then you need to put **AND** in that string only.not here after **where condition**..thx.

Comment: i tried it no errors always show "Showing: 1 to 10 of 99 Listings" when search through the form and also it will not show the results

Comment: can you provide me the full query which have been executed.? just **echo** your query and send me...i'll try to fine errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is here:

```
     $all_p = mysql_query($sql.$sort);
     $totalRows_p = mysql_num_rows($all_p);
```

from the message you get $all_p is not a valid resource. This might be due to an error in the query you are passing

have you tried doing this?

```
     $all_p = mysql_query($sql.$sort);
     if ($all_p !== false){
         $totalRows_p = mysql_num_rows($all_p);
     }
```

if you see no warning you have a problem with your query and you should debug that. Try to execute you query in mysql and look if any results are returned.

Comment: i tried by replacing your subjection, but now no any results show

Comment: That means that your query has an error. 
Here yo echo your query: `echo "<hr>Property with out limit SQL: $sql $sort";` Have you tried to run your query into mysql?

Comment: If you run your query you have no result in mysql?Can you show your quwery?

Answer (score 0):

You're using direct assignment for `$search` when you want array assignment. This means that when you go to implode it, it probably returns false(??? I've never suppressed warnings on implode. I have no idea what that does.). That is being misread when appended to $sql. You then append $sort and $limit to $sql and then prepend $sql again for good measure before calling mysql_query. You're also not checking to see if $_REQUEST['city'] and $_REQUEST['desitination'] have values.

Your final result (worse case):

```
select * FROM properties WHERE type= "'.$type.'" and  select * FROM properties WHERE type= "'.$type.'" and order by added asc Limit 0,10
```

Your final result (best case):

```
select * FROM properties WHERE type= "'.$type.'" and city = 'Atlanta' select * FROM properties WHERE type= "'.$type.'" and city = 'Atlanta' order by added asc Limit 0,10
```

Add this at the top:

```
$search = array();
```

and then any time you want to append `$search`:

```
$search[] = ' district = '.$_REQUEST['district'];
```

And replace this line `$searchResults = mysql_query($sql.$sql_with_limit);` with:

```
$searchResults = mysql_query($sql_with_limit);
```

BTW you're begging for SQL injection here. Any time you pull a value from `$_REQUEST`, you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string`.